# android device ID generation gives an error

Tags: android, device, telephonymanager

In my **Android** app I wanna generate the **device ID**. At first I just generate the **device ID** inside an **activity** as below. It worked fine.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
return uid;
```

Then I wanna create a device **object** and try to do the above in it as a method,

```
public String generateDeviceId() {
    // DeviceId = deviceId;

    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
    return uid;

}
```

It gives an **syntax error** and say

> The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Device

So how can I fix this. I wanna create a device class and create **device object** and do my stuff. Is it possible. I imported the below,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

So is it possible. Can someone help me to do my work. Thanks.

Comment: Device is a class a non Activity class?

Comment: yes. how can i generate the deviceID in the Device class.

Answer (score 1):

When  you try to access  getSystemService outside of the android activity class then you must need the context.

```
    TelephonyManager tm = 
(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

and this are complete method

```
    public String generateDeviceId(Context context) {
        // DeviceId = deviceId;

        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)context. getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
        return uid;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: not working. gives a syntax error. it says "context cannot be resolved"

Comment: ok now its working....

Answer (score 1):

`getSystemService(String)` needs a context. So you need to pass context to the constructor of Non Activity class and use it there.

```
new  Device(ActivityName.this);
```

Then

```
Context mContext;
public Device(Context context) 
{
     mContext = context;
}
```

Then

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this method in your Device class

```
public String generateDeviceId(Context context) {
   // DeviceId = deviceId;
   TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
   return uid;
}
```

and While calling from your `Activity` , just pass the current activity reference `this`

```
 deviceObject.generateDeviceId(this);
```